# Can Users have other Users in a Relationship in Django?

Tags: django, relationship, django-users

So, I am fairly new to Django and I know there is just one `User` type. I am wondering what is the best way for me to go about setting up my models.

My site needs 4 different types of users: admins (including superuser), teachers, students, parents. I want only admin to be able to use the built in admin UI. I want teachers to have some admin features but only on frontend UI.

So far I have extended AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager to create users that can be assigned the 4 roles mentioned above and a few different things. They are working and I can manage authorization of page views with them, but this is just scratching the surface of what I hope to do.

But how do I manage this when I want a teacher to have many students in a class and only see those students when they login? I want these students to be assigned to teacher by the admin and then allow the teacher to have some permissions with the student info.

Can I use signals to create a `Teacher` model that belongs to a`User` with a `role` of teacher and that same `Teacher` model ``` has_many`` ```Student``` s. The ``Student ``` would also have been created instantly with the `User` having a `role` of `student`.

I am thinking along the lines of how you would create a `Profile` with a new `User`.

I know how to associate Teachers and Students and Parents, etc but it is confusing to me when they are all user types as well.

Or is there a way to do this with just keeping them as ``Users``` with roles and relating them in another way?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this :-

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html

I think this is the answer you are looking for.

Let me know if you need further explanation.

Happy coding :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am able to do that with extending AbstractBaseUser. Not exactly like he did but close. Now how do I make one user have many of the other?